# Storing a list from a textfile

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a textfile that contains a list on the first line.
How can I read the file and store the first line in a list?
I want to store the first line as a complete list not as a string.

Example of the textfile:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
```

Comment: 2 upvotes? There's clearly no attempt by the OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your data is valid json:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]')
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

To load it from a file:

```
with open('my_file.txt') as f:
    my_list = json.load(f)
```

Similarly, `yaml.load` and `ast.literal_eval` could also handle that data.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ast` module

```
import ast

s = '[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]'
s = ast.literal_eval(s)
print s, type(s)

>>> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]] <type 'list'>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) like below:

```
>>> import ast
>>>
>>> ast.literal_eval('[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]')
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

This is why you should use `ast.literal_eval()` to evaluate your string:

> ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)
>
> Safely evaluate an expression node or
>   a string containing a Python literal or container display. The string
>   or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal
>   structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets,
>   booleans, and None.